# TwiML Bin - Anyway to access parameters?

Tags: xml, twilio, twilio-twiml

I am setting up a demo for a product, and we are using Twilio two connect two people together. To host the XML response, I set up new TwiML bin files that Twilio offers. I am using the `<Gather>` call to prompt the first caller to hit 1 to accept or 2 to decline.

Is there anyway to check the `Digits` parameter from the `Gather` in a TwiML bin file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here. Unfortunately, to get the value from the [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather), you will need a backend server as Twilio will make and HTTP POST or GET request to your page with that digit.

Luckily doing that is pretty simple, and you could put something in place fairly quickly by just deploying it to one of your servers, or even a free Heroku instance.

From your question, I can't quite tell what programming language you're using, but if you wanted to do this in say PHP, you could do something like this:

```
<?php
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
echo "<Response><Say>You entered " . $_REQUEST['Digits'] . "</Say></Response>";
?>
```

Another way you could do this is by using the [twimlets](https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets) website.

Have a look at [this example](https://www.twilio.com/labs/twimlets/menu). You could then create your logic with TwiMLBin to redirect the user.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Appreciate it. This demo is for an app inside of Cordova, so I don't have a server stood up (and putting something on our companies server in time for the demo is pretty much out of the question).

Thanks for the info!

Comment: I think Twimlet is exactly what I need! Thank you.

Comment: Is there a way to change the voice of the twimlet apps?

Comment: I'm using node.js and I'm using below code, however after pressing the key it says an application error occurred instead of Thank you.
_
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    var call=req.query.CallSid;
    var digit=req.query.Digits;
    firebase.database().ref('CallDetails/').set({
        callSid: call,
        digit : digit
      });
      res.type('application/text');
    res.end("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Response><Say>Thank you</Say></Response>");
});