# TwiML keeps going to top after <gather> tag

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I am new to using Twilio, and am having some difficulty using TwiML. I have created a basic python script, that calls on my TwiML in a TwiML bin hosted by Twilio. This works great, the calls are being made and my TwiML is clearly being called. However, in my TwiML, after the "gather" tag is reached, unless the user presses the finishKey, it immediately returns to the top and starts the TwiML from the top again! I have tried numerous varieties, but can't figure out how to make it work! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>

  <Gather timeout="5" finishOnKey="#" input="dtmf">
        <Say>Location name: THE LOCATION. Enter number, then press pound. </Say>
    </Gather>

  <Gather timeout="5" finishOnKey="#" input="dtmf">
        <Say>Enter number, then press pound.</Say>
    </Gather>
  <Say>
Response recorded. Goodbye
  </Say>
</Response>
```

Comment: Without an action URL, Twilio will re-request the URL that hosts the TwiML you just executed. In short you'll need a back-end server or use a Twilio function. Maybe this answer can also help (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37258431/twiml-bin-anyway-to-access-parameters)

Comment: Understood! Thank You!